# Turning Keras Model layer within model into multiple layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I currently have an architecture using the Functional API that incorporates ResNet50, but when building my model with additional layers, it treats ResNet as a Model layer, rather than a series of layers. Is there any way to turn this model layer into a series of layers, without using the Sequential API? I essentially want to turn this model within a model into just a model. (Not simply printing out the layers, or anything) This is the model architecture, showing the current model with the resnet50 "layer".

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
main_input (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
aux_input (InputLayer)          (None, 224, 224, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_4 (Lambda)               (None, 224, 224, 3)  0           main_input[0][0]                 
                                                                 aux_input[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
resnet50 (Model)                (None, 2)            23591810    lambda_4[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
```

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this? Resnet is a bit more than a series of layers.

Comment: Good question. I've been trying to work on a loss function that uses intermediate layer outputs, and am beginning to suspect that the "nested" style of model may be to blame for issues I've been encountering. Basically I have tried to access layers from the resnet within a model using `mymodel.layers[-1].layers[-6].output` which is failing, and I'm hoping that by not having the nested-style model layer, something like `mymodel.layers[-6].output` it would run. Yes, the complexity of resnet is why I'm avoiding a sequential approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a workaround than a true answer, but my solution in this case was to totally re-implement the resnet50 achitecture using the functional api, with my added layers as necessary. See [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9721) example. 
By using this approach, there is no "model" nested layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can kinda trick this, yeah. But the other comment/answers aren't kidding, it's a lot to look at, especially since it prints out linearly, whereas it doesn't tend to be easy to visualize the flow of data in that way. Here are some details that might assist you.

- You can get the layers from model.layers, which will include anything you added onto it.
- You can reference these layers, like `layer_001 = model.layers[0]`.

  - if you want to keep them in the existing model pipeline, you can change their attributes within the model (e.g. adding regularization: `model.layers[-7].bias_regularizer=l2(0.001)`)
  - if you're referencing them explicitly like the example `layer_001`, you will need to rebuild and recompile the new model pipeline before fitting.

If you can think of a neat loopy way to do this to all layers, that might be fine, but otherwise it's going to be a lot of work to recreate the whole thing this way. I'd agree with the other comments/answers and just recreate it from scratch with help from [Papers with Code](https://paperswithcode.com/).

If you just want to modify a couple attributes on a few layers, I'd just reference them inside the model (as above) and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function simalr to this:

```
def DeCapsule(model,LayerName):
    GotInnerModel = False
    for layer in model.layers[1:]:
        if not GotInnerModel:
            if layer.name ==LayerName:
                MiddleModel = layer
                Out = layer.layers[-1].output
                GotInnerModel = True
        else:
            Out = layer(Out)

    Out = Model(inputs=MiddleModel.layers[0].input, outputs=Out)        
    return Out
```